# How can i post multiply objects in array and get the data in the action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Web API and posting works fine when I send one object.  How can I send this type here.

Until now I have tried this approach, https://ibb.co/dKztDGv, but without success.  I don't get an error but I get the values from the last object only. Please help me get all the values in the array.

```
//I post this type of objects in array 
[
 {something...},
 {something...}
]

//what I've tried
public IActionResult PostNewLanguages([FromBody] JObject newLanguages, string id)
{
    var oneUser = GetSpecificUser(id);
    JObject class1DataJson = newLanguages;
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731755/asp-net-core-posting-array-object-json?

Comment: or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573384/how-to-post-arbitrary-json-object-to-webapi?

Comment: First of all thanks to you reply,But how can i acces to request in this case?{'reques't:{} , {} } , in run time , request will hold the data for all objects,but in compile time there is an error

Comment: What is the compile time error that you get?

Comment: For example i have [FromBody] obj and in compile time ofcourse obj.request does not work and i get that obj dont have such a property...

Comment: I've editted my answer.  You need to get at the data using a key.

Comment: Thanks for your time sir.But i get this now {[   {id:1} , {id:2}   ]} how to go inside,i send object like you said

Comment: I dont know if JOJBECTS GAVE extra {}

Comment: i meaned how can i dynamicly make variables  as data holder for every object

Answer (score 0):

When I run this and send an array of objects I get this error

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

So I suggest trying to send something like this instead

```
{ "myData": [
    {something...},
    {something...}
]}
```

And then to access the data you will need to do

```
var myValues = newLanguages["myData"];

foreach(var value in myValues)
{
}
```

'myData' being whatever key you use for your array.  Looks like 'request' in your case going by your comments.

Comment: Thank you.But in the controlles how i will acces to the objects?

Answer (score 0):

If you post an array of object, you need to receive it as a List like

```
public IActionResult PostNewLanguages([FromBody] List<JObject> newLanguages, string id)
{
    foreach(var obj in newLanguages)
    {

    }

    return Ok();
}
```